# Writing and Reading DataGridView to text file

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm looking for some assistance on how to populate a DataGridView control with data from a text file. The column number is static, but the row count is dynamic. I am using StreamWriter to create the text file line by line. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnSaveReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveReport.Click
    Dim path As String = "c:\users\service5\desktop\ReportFile.txt"

    Using writer As New StreamWriter(path)

        For row As Integer = 0 To dgvLabor.RowCount - 2
            For col As Integer = 0 To dgvLabor.ColumnCount - 1
                writer.WriteLine("Labor" & "|" & dgvLabor.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value)
            Next
        Next

        writer.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

The output file looks like this:

```
Labor|Mon 09/25/2017
Labor|Labor Time
Labor|11:42 PM
Labor|12:42 AM
Labor|23.00
Labor|20
```

I'm stumped when using the StreamReader method to read each line from the text file and place it in the correct column and row. I had success populating text boxes using the "|" delimited format, but I'm not sure how to go about tackling the DataGridView code. Would it be wise to reformat my StreamWriter method to make the file comma delimited instead of "|" delimited?

**UPDATE 10/08/2017**

Ok, I have the writer formatting the text file the way I want and the StreamReader is 95% working. It successfully populates the DataGridView for the first row, but it needs to recognize every line beginning with "Labor" and add a new row with the array in the line. Here is a sample of the text I'm trying to read into the DataGridView.

```
Labor,Sun 10/08/2017,Labor Time,12:39 AM,12:39 AM,0.00,0
Labor,Mon 10/09/2017,Travel Time,12:39 AM,12:39 AM,0.00,0
```

Here is the StreamReader code:

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

    Dim FileReader As StreamReader
    Dim prop(2) As String
    Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    FileReader = New StreamReader(path, False)

    Do Until FileReader.EndOfStream

        prop = FileReader.ReadLine().Split(",")

    If String.Equals(prop(0), "Labor") Then

            Dim col(6) As String
            Dim index = dgvLabor.Rows.Add()
            col = FileReader.ReadLine().Split(",")
            dgvLabor.Rows(index).SetValues(col(1), col(2), col(3), col(4), col(5), col(6))

        End If
    Loop

    FileReader.Close()

End Sub
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the number of lines beginning with "Labor" will vary every time the text file is written, so I think I need a Do Until or Do While loop within the If String.Equals method, but I cannot get the syntax right. I've tried these so far with no success:

```
Do While String.Equals("Labor")
Do Until String.Equals(Not "Labor")
Do Until String.Equals(prop(0), "Labor")
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION 10/09/2017**

After really thinking about what my code is doing, I finally solved the problem. It's stupid simple and proves how much I was overthinking everything. Thanks for your assistance and patience with me, jmcilhinney. Hope this can help someone else out as well.

```
        ElseIf String.Equals(prop(0), "Labor") Then

            dgvLabor.Rows.Add(prop(1), prop(2), prop(3), prop(4), prop(5), prop(6))

        End If
```

Comment: Is the grid going to start empty when you read the file or will it already be populated and you want to update the existing data?

Comment: The grid will start empty when the file is read.

Comment: In that case there is no placing anything in the correct row because there are no rows to begin with.  You would use a `Do` or `While` loop to read the data and, on each iteration, create a new row, populate it and then add it to the grid. I find it hard to believe that you can't find an example of populating a `DataGridView` from a CSV file on the web. The fact that your delimiter is not a comma is basically irrelevant because you simply split on whatever character you like when you read the data.

Comment: I found a few examples online, but wasn't sure if they would work for my application. I wasn't aware that if the grid is empty, the coding becomes a little more simple.

Comment: Online examples should work unless there is some specific, relevant difference in your situation. If there is, we can help you with that specific issue when you encounter it.

Comment: Updated original post with some code. Having trouble looping each line into the DataGridView. Please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to add just the records from the file that begin with "Labor" and ignore the rest?  In that case, think about what your code is doing.  You read a line, detect that it begins with "Labor" and then you... read another line.  Unless your intention is to add only the lines after those that begin with "Labor", why would you read another line when you've just determined that the current line begins with "Labor"?

Comment: By the way, don't specify a size when you declare the array variable.  What's the point, given that what that does is create an array of that size and assign it to the variable?  You never use that array because `ReadLine` creates a new array every time.  Don't create things if you're not going to use them.

Comment: Yes, any line that begins with "Labor" I want added as a new row to the DataGrid and each comma specifies the next cell in that row.  I get what you're saying about reading a line and then reading another. Would I be better off using the ReadAllLines method or continue using StreamReader?

Comment: No, you would be better off just not reading another line when you've already got the one you want to add to the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After really thinking about what my code is doing, I finally solved the problem. It's stupid simple and proves how much I was overthinking everything. Thanks for your assistance and patience with me, jmcilhinney. Hope this can help someone else out as well.

```
        ElseIf String.Equals(prop(0), "Labor") Then

            dgvLabor.Rows.Add(prop(1), prop(2), prop(3), prop(4), prop(5), prop(6))

        End If
```

This code takes the already split line and inserts the desired objects of the array into the next available row's cells. It only adds the lines in the text document that begin with "Labor"